# jQuery datatable - ASP.NET controller parameter always null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have the following JavaScript function...

```
function loadTable(date: string) {
  $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
    "bServerSide": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "Date/GetValuesFromDate",
    "data": date
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
      { "sName": "MESSAGE" },
      { "sName": "DATE" },
      { "sName": "STATUS" }
    ]
    "bDestroy":true
  });

...
```

That calls the following controller on my ASP.NET WEb Application...

```
public class DateController : Controller
{
  private RegistrationDbContext _context;

  public HomeController(RegistrationDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  public ActionResult GetValuesFromDate(string date)
  {
    // Some code here...
    return Json(new
      {
        aaData = results;
      });
  }
}
```

However, the value of the **string date** is always null. I saw that the loadTable() function does contain the date so I have no clue now how to pass that out to the Controller itself...

I hardcoded the date and everything works wonderfull so the only missing piece here is the binding between the JavaScript function and the Controller...

Any pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: In JavaScript you have "data": date, this means the date being sent has parameter name of data. Try changing it to "date":date

Comment: I changed to "date":date and it is still null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try capturing the sent information via Fiddler and show us the request that is being sent.

Comment: What time of object is date?

Comment: date is a string object (like this "12/14/2015")

Answer (score 1):

Trying wrapping up the data param in {} IE

```
'data': {'date': date}
```

OR you could directly append it to your source url I think as a query string since it is a GET...

```
"sAjaxSource": "Date/GetValuesFromDate?date=" + date
```

Comment: Appending the date to the sAjaxSource worked! Thanks a lot!. I will try to investigate it further though as I don't like that design as a permanent solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know that is icky and I wouldn't recommend doing it permanently...I haven't played with DataTables for awhile though so I was offering it up as an alternative solution and one that hopefully will get you along enough until you can implement a better one